# #include is required sooner than it appears in the program

Tags: c, include, c-preprocessor

I have a header where one of the functions declare if `DEBUG` is defined.

Also I have a definition of this function which works the same principle. But I will know if `DEBUG` is defined only in `main()` after arguments checking.

I've placed the `#include` in `main()`:

**header:**

```
#ifdef DEBUG
void printStack(Stack* st);
#endif
```

**file where function definition is**

```
#ifdef DEBUG
void printStack(Stack* st)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < st->size; i++)
        printf(ValType_IOSPECIF " ",st->data[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
#endif
```

**file where main() is**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "calculating.h"

#define EXPR_LENGTH 1000

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int argflag = 0;
    if (argc >= 2)
        argflag = !strcmp(argv[1], "-debug");

#if (argflag)
#define DEBUG
    printf("! DEBUG !\n\n\n")
#endif

#include "stack.h" // there is a that function here
...
}
```

Is it right?

Comment: "where one of the functions declare if DEBUG" - No, the function is defined if `DEBUG` is defined. And you should pass this macro from the command-line, not define it in your code. And in general it is a bad idea to exclude the whole function, as that will make your code not compiler without it.

Comment: Run `gcc -E main.c`, and check the result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing C and preprocessor macros:

Everything starting with a `#` is replaced by the preprocessor, before the source code gets compiled, and only at runtime there's `main` executing.

So, no, you're not doing it right.

You can't `#define` or `#if` at runtime; it's a pre-compile-time thing. Simply use C's normal variables and `if` control mechanisms.

Your mistakes strongly point to you not going through a coherent tutorial or C book to learn the language. Maybe you want to pick up new literature; any C tutorial I could possibly imagine will teach you how to do this pretty quickly.

Answer (score 4):

> But I will know if DEBUG is defined only into main() after arguments checking.
>
> ...
>
> Is it right?

No, that is not right.

`DEBUG` is a preprocessor macro that is defined, or not, at compile time when compiling each source file. It is possible that `DEBUG` is defined when compiling `main.c` but not when compiling the source file that defines `printStack`.

If you use `make` or an IDE, it is most likely that `DEBUG` is defined, or not, for compiling every source file but there is nothing in the language that guarantees that.

Comment: IIRC, it was the `NDEBUG` macro. Nost sure if `DEBUG` is actually supported.

Comment: @Olaf, the standard talks about `NDEBUG` in relation to `assert`. I think of the OP is wondering about `DEBUG` that has no relation to `NDEBUG`.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect he actually thinks about somethink like `NDEBUG` though, but either confused the name or just follows hearsay.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's wrong. you're trying to determine the result of preprocess according to the arguments passed. Here is the simplified version of your code:

```
#define EXPR_LENGTH 1000

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int argflag = 0;
    if (argc >= 2)
        argflag = !strcmp(argv[1], "-debug");

#if (argflag)
#define DEBUG
    printf("! DEBUG !\n\n\n")
#endif
}
```

Preprocessed with `clang -E main.c`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 int argflag = 0;
 if (argc >= 2)
  argflag = !strcmp(argv[1], "-debug");





}
```

*Pre*process is finished before compilation, which is before execution, starts. So it's impossible to determine the result of preprocess at run-time.